# Tangent space to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $T_{x_{0}}M$ dentotes the tangent space to topological manifold $M$ at point $x_{0}$. Let $M=\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $T_{x_{0}}\mathbb{R}=x_{0}$?

Comment: The tangent space to $\Bbb R$ at any point is a copy of $\Bbb R$, not a single point.

Comment: What's the tangent space of a topological manifold?

Comment: I define it as a set of equicalence classes. But in this particular case, there is no need to use such an abstract definition, I guess.

Comment: You could say that $T_{x_{0}}\mathbb{R}$ is spanned by $x_0$, but that is a round about way of saying it is just a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Answer (score 3):

It's obviously not true. For example by a dimensional argument : $\mathbf R$ is of dimension 1 when $\{x_0\}$ is of dimension $0$.

So, how to find $T_{x_0}\mathbf R$ ? It depends on what we call "tangent space" but the easiest way is to define it is as the space of the derivatives $c'(0)$ of curves $c:]-\epsilon , \epsilon [\to \mathbf R$ of class $C^1$ such that $c(0)=x_0$.

Now, what are the different values of $c'(0)$ given a curve $c$ ? Of course, $c'(0)$ is a real number, so $T_{x_0}\mathbf R \subseteq \mathbf R$. Conversely, given $\lambda\in \mathbf R$, the curve $c(t) = t \lambda + x_0$ gives $c'(0)=\lambda$. This is why $T_{x_0}\mathbf R=\mathbf R$.

Furthermore, this identification is in fact independent of the choice of $x_0$. It's always the "same" $\mathbf R$ which appears when you take the tangent space of a point in $\mathbf R$.